# Chrome devtools frontend: Screencast is too small

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am running Chrome devtools front-end in my webapp to show a webpage. The problem is the screencast is too small and does not fill up the entire canvas. How can I tell it to be 100% width and height?

[image]